# How do I get Ingo to provide sieve rules suitable for use with DSPAM?

Tags: spam, sieve, horde, dspam

Using the Ingo web gui which is part of horde, I can set up sieve rules that get written to file like so:

```
# Junk-Review
if header :comparator "i;ascii-casemap" :regex "X-DSPAM-confidence" "^(0\.[0-8][0-9]{3})$"  {
    fileinto "Junk-Review";
    stop;
}
# Junk
if header :comparator "i;ascii-casemap" :contains "X-DSPAM-Result" "Spam"  {
    fileinto "Junk";
    stop;
}
```

I'd like to provide these rules such that they are available to all users, and default to running at the proper point, after things like whitelist and blacklist, but before custom rules.

Is there a way to get ingo to do this?  By default it's very much oriented towards the way Spamassassin writes its headers, and it only caters for a 2 way split between Spam and non-Spam, which leaves the user still needing to review all their spam in order to catch the few false positives.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to people on the IRC channel the developers of Horde use.  Sounds like there is no good solution.